# Writing and reading arrays of structs in C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to write an array of structs to a binary file, and then read that file after re-running the code, but I get a segmentation fault every time I try to read it. It seems to read only one byte and then run into the segmentation fault error. I'm not sure if it reads only one byte or writes only one byte.

This is how I save it:

```
if (current_id == 0){
                    printf("No records to be saved.\n");
                    break;
                }
                FILE *save_data;
                if ((save_data = fopen("student_records.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }
                printf("%lu", fwrite(sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, save_data));
                fclose(save_data);

                FILE *save_ID;
                if ((save_ID = fopen("record_count", "w")) == NULL) {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }
                putw(current_id, save_ID);
                fclose(save_ID);
                printf("File saved.");
```

This is how I read it

```
FILE* load_ID;
                load_ID = fopen("record_count", "r");
                current_id = getw(load_ID);
                fclose(load_ID);

                FILE* load_data;
                if ((load_data = fopen("student_records.bin", "rb")) == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }

                printf("%lu", fread(sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, load_data));
                fclose(load_data);

                printf("%s", sr_list[0].first_name);
```

The counter variable seems to write and read fine. Only the array of structs seems to fail. Here is how I initialize the variables

```
    int const num_students = 2000;
    int current_id = 0;
    StudentRecord *sr_list = malloc(num_students * sizeof(StudentRecord));
```

Here is the entire code just in case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct StudentRecordTag {
    int ID;
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    float *grades;
    int num_grades;
    int days_absent;
    char *memo;
} StudentRecord;

StudentRecord make_student_record(
        int ID,
        char const *first_name,
        char const *last_name,
        float const *grades,
        int num_grades,
        int days_absent,
        char *memo
) {
    StudentRecord sr;
    sr.ID = ID;
    sr.days_absent = days_absent;
    sr.num_grades = num_grades;
    if (first_name != NULL) {
        sr.first_name = malloc(strlen(first_name) + 1);
        if (sr.first_name != NULL) {
            strcpy(sr.first_name, first_name);
        }
    }
    if (last_name != NULL) {
        sr.last_name = malloc(strlen(last_name) + 1);
        if (sr.last_name != NULL) {
            strcpy(sr.last_name, last_name);
        }
    }
    if (grades != NULL) {
        sr.grades = malloc(num_grades * sizeof(float));
        if (sr.grades != NULL) {
            memcpy(sr.grades, grades, num_grades * sizeof(float));
        }
    }
    if (memo != NULL) {
        sr.memo = malloc(strlen(memo) + 1);
        if (sr.memo != NULL) {
            strcpy(sr.memo, memo);
        }
    }
    printf("\nStudent Record made.");
    return sr;
}

void destroy_student_record(StudentRecord *p_sr) {
    free(p_sr->first_name);
    free(p_sr->last_name);
    free(p_sr->grades);
    free(p_sr->memo);

    p_sr->ID = 0;
    p_sr->first_name = NULL;
    p_sr->last_name = NULL;
    p_sr->grades = NULL;
    p_sr->num_grades = 0;
    p_sr->days_absent = 0;
    p_sr->memo = NULL;
}

void print_student_records(StudentRecord sr_list[], int num_students) {
    for (int student_idx = 0; student_idx < num_students;
         ++student_idx) {

        if (sr_list[student_idx].first_name == NULL) break;

        printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
        printf("ID: %d\n", sr_list[student_idx].ID);
        printf("First Name: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].first_name);
        printf("Last Name: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].last_name);
        printf("Grades: ");
        int num_grades = sr_list[student_idx].num_grades;
        //printf("___________________\n %d", num_grades);
        for (int grade_idx = 0; grade_idx < num_grades; ++grade_idx) {
            printf("(%d) %3.1f", grade_idx + 1,
                   sr_list[student_idx].grades[grade_idx]);
            if (grade_idx < num_grades - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            } else {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("Days Absent: %d\n",
               sr_list[student_idx].days_absent);
        printf("Memo: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].memo);
        printf("\n");

        //destroy_student_record(&sr_list[student_idx]);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(StudentRecord));

    int const num_students = 2000;
    int current_id = 0;
    //StudentRecord sr_list[num_students];
    StudentRecord *sr_list = malloc(num_students * sizeof(StudentRecord));
/*    int const num_grades = 3;
    //float* const grades = malloc(num_grades * sizeof(float));
    float const grades[num_grades] = {50, 75.5f, 32.1f};

    sr_list[0] = make_student_record(
            0,
            "Johnny",
            "Doeberman",
            grades,
            num_grades,
            12,
            "This student never came to class!"
    );*/
    //print_student_records(sr_list, num_students);
    /*for (int student_idx = 0; student_idx < num_students;
         ++student_idx) {

        printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
        printf("ID: %d\n", sr_list[student_idx].ID);
        printf("First Name: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].first_name);
        printf("Last Name: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].last_name);
        printf("Grades: ");
        for (int grade_idx = 0; grade_idx < num_grades; ++grade_idx) {
            printf("(%d) %3.1f", grade_idx + 1,
                   sr_list[student_idx].grades[grade_idx]);
            if (grade_idx < num_grades - 1) {
                printf(", ");
            } else {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("Days Absent: %d\n",
               sr_list[student_idx].days_absent);
        printf("Memo: %s\n", sr_list[student_idx].memo);
        printf("\n");

        destroy_student_record(&sr_list[student_idx]);
    }*/
    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        int selection;
        printf("\nType the number corresponding to the option.\n\n"
               "Option 1: View student records\n"
               "Option 2: Add new record\n"
               "Option 3: Save current list\n"
               "Option 4: Load records from save file\n"
               "Option 5: Exit\n"
               "Enter an option number: ");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        getchar();

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                print_student_records(sr_list, num_students);
                break;

            case 2: {
                char *new_firstname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
                char *new_lastname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
                float *new_grades = malloc(sizeof(float) * 15);
                int *new_num_grades = malloc(sizeof(int));
                int *new_days_absent = malloc(sizeof(int));
                char *new_memo = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2500);
                printf("Enter the first name: ");
                fgets(new_firstname, 200, stdin);
                new_firstname[strcspn(new_firstname, "\n")] = 0;
                printf("\nEnter the last name: ");
                fgets(new_lastname, 200, stdin);
                new_lastname[strcspn(new_lastname, "\n")] = 0;
                printf("\nEnter the number of grades: ");
                scanf("%d", new_num_grades);
                getchar();
                for (int i = 0; i < *new_num_grades; i++) {
                    printf("Enter grade %d: ", i + 1);
                    scanf("%f", &new_grades[i]);
                    getchar();
                }
                printf("\nEnter the days absent: ");
                scanf("%d", new_days_absent);
                getchar();
                printf("\nEnter a note: ");
                fgets(new_memo, 2500, stdin);
                new_memo[strcspn(new_memo, "\n")] = 0;
                sr_list[current_id] = make_student_record(current_id + 1, new_firstname,
                                                          new_lastname, new_grades,
                                                          *new_num_grades, *new_days_absent, new_memo);
                current_id++;
                free(new_firstname);
                free(new_lastname);
                free(new_grades);
                free(new_num_grades);
                free(new_days_absent);
                free(new_memo);
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                if (current_id == 0){
                    printf("No records to be saved.\n");
                    break;
                }
                FILE *save_data;
                if ((save_data = fopen("student_records.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }
                printf("%lu", fwrite(sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, save_data));
                fclose(save_data);

                FILE *save_ID;
                if ((save_ID = fopen("record_count", "w")) == NULL) {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }
                putw(current_id, save_ID);
                fclose(save_ID);
                printf("File saved.");

                break;
            }

            case 4: {
                FILE* load_ID;
                load_ID = fopen("record_count", "r");
                current_id = getw(load_ID);
                fclose(load_ID);

                FILE* load_data;
                if ((load_data = fopen("student_records.bin", "rb")) == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                    break;
                }

                printf("%lu", fread(sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, load_data));
                fclose(load_data);

                printf("%s", sr_list[0].first_name);
                break;
            }

            case 5:
                running = false;
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nTry again.");
        }
    }

    printf("bye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't save strings by writing pointers to the file.

Comment: You're just writing the addresses to the file, not the contents of the strings they point to. And when you read the file, you get the addresses from the old process, which aren't valid any more.

Comment: When you `printf("%lu", fwrite(sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, save_data));`, `current_id` is zero, so you are writing nothing to the file.

Comment: You can investigate your *problem* by only writing/reading **a single** struct to/from file. No need to use four structs until you know how to manage one struct.

Comment: Use a debugger and check which line caused the error. Then investigate the parameters of the function call, and if the values are not expected, move on from there and investigate some more. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for debugging. You might be able to use Stack Overflow as a debugger for some days but then it'll come back to haunt you. Just learn how to debug. Debugging is an essential skill.

Answer (score 0):

You must to pass pointer to fwrite, like here:

```c
fwrite(&sr_list, sizeof(StudentRecord) * current_id, 1, save_data)
```

"&" before `sr_list` means, that you taking pointer to sr_list array

Comment: Arrays automatically decay to pointers in these situations.